# How to apply multiple methods on the same data element in FastAPI

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, endpoint

I want to perform the following processing of a String variable received as a parameter of my API endpoint (FastAPI) as shown below, and I have 30 functions that need to be applied to the String variable.
I'm kind of lost and don't really know how can I do this, any hints, or concepts I should learn about that can help solve the problem.

---

Code:

````
 
def func1(data):
    return True
def func2(data):
    return True
def func3(data):
    return True
...

def func30(data):
    return True


@app.get("/process/{data}")
def process(data):
    # Apply all the methods on the data variable 
    return response ```

----------


thank you
````

Comment: why do you have that much of functions ? what's the use of that exactly ?

Comment: I'm analysing the text, each function is doing a different job than the other, eg, one function is extracting all the numbers existing in the text, the other one is translating it to another language ... And the thing is, I want them all invoked when the endpoint is requested

Comment: your functions have the same pattern name ? i mean func1 func2 .. or they have a completely different names (like : func, toto, etc) ?

Comment: yeah, they have the same pattern name

Comment: Create a list of all the functions you want to apply and in which sequence, then iterate over the list and apply the functions as you iterate. I'm guessing you want to archive the return data to a dict or something similar, since it doesn't seem like you're applying the next function to the result of the previous one? In that case you can use a dict to keep the function instead, with the key of your resulting structure as the key and the function as the value; iterate over it using `.items()` and assign each processed value to the result dict.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing this, but the problem is how exactly to iterate and apply methods, is there any built-in function that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` with a list of functions and turn it into a list, as `map` is lazily evaluated. You may ignore the list if not needed.

```py
def apply(data, functions):
    return list(map(lambda f: f(data), functions))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Any


def apply(funcs, data):
    return reduce(lambda tmp, func: func(tmp), funcs, data)


funcs = [
    lambda x: x + 'a',
    lambda x: x + 'b',
    lambda x: x + 'c',
    lambda x: x + 'd',
]

print(apply(funcs, ''))  # Result is 'abcd'
```